# Time difference between two columns in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to calculate time difference in hours between two columns in pyspark.
Below is the sample dataframe. The columns are String type (yyyymmddhhmmss).

```
time1           time2
20191020051010  20191019051010
```

Want the below output. Here 24 represents the difference between time1 and time2 in hours.

```
time1                time2         diff
20191020051010  20191019051010     24
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn(
    'diff',
    (F.unix_timestamp(F.to_timestamp(F.col('time1')))) - 
    (F.unix_timestamp(F.to_timestamp(F.col('time2'))))/F.lit(3600)
)
```

Comment: But it's throwing null value. Please note I'm using python 3.6 and spark 2.7.... Please refer to the below code I'm using ==========================================================    mySchema = StructType([StructField("Time1", StringType())\
                      ,StructField("Time2", StringType())])
test_lst = [['20191019051010', '20191020051010']]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(test_lst,schema=mySchema)
df1.show()
df1.printSchema()

df1 = df1.withColumn('unixTime1',F.unix_timestamp(F.to_timestamp(F.col('Time1'))))\
    .withColumn('toTime1',F.to_timestamp(F.col('Time1')))
df1.show()

Comment: @NabarunChakraborti This will work - `df = df.withColumn('diff', (F.unix_timestamp('time1', 'yyyyMMddhhmmss') -F.unix_timestamp('time2', 'yyyyMMddhhmmss'))/3600)`

Comment: I don't know why still I'm getting null values. below is the schema -  '|-- Time1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Time2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- diff: double (nullable = true)'